# Contributing sample code for Google Glass

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I want to contribute a new sample app for Google Glass. The CONTRIBUTING.MD states that I need to create a new repo, and

> request to fork your repo in googleglass organization

Given that I am not a part of the *googleglass* organization on Github, how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Reach out to Google by filing an issue in the Google Glass platform [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) with a link to the repository that you'd like them to fork.

Comment: Does that mean, that you want this sample code to be a part of one of your existing repositories ? Is there a folder structure that you wanted to maintain ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. You're interested in contributing a completely new sample, rather than an addition to an existing repo. I updated my answer to reflect this.